# How to put html inside a SVG device prototype?

Tags: html, css, svg

So basically what I want to do is this:

Lets take this svg as an example:

https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/blank-screen-laptop-gadget-icon-white-background_9306518.htm

What I want to do in my next.js project is following:

- Put my own code inside the "monitor" area of this notebook.
- Also make this responsible

So I need a good way to display the notebook and then I create my own div thats the same height and width as the notebook screen and I can put anything else I want into it (paragraphs, h1 etc). So it seems that my code / page appears directly onto the notebook screen.

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

I heard about clip-path but I wasn't able to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

Or no SVG at all

Make the laptop PNG screen transparent, and position it over your content

[image]

```html
<style>
#LAPTOP{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
#SCREEN,#BORDER{
  position:absolute;
}
#SCREEN{
  margin:1em;
  margin-left:3em;
}
#MAP{
  zoom:.5;
}
#BORDER{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:999;
}
</style>

<div id="LAPTOP">
  <div id="SCREEN">
   <b>Hello World!</b>
   <img id="MAP" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/7OrKxhEgjUlMNO280hA_iums8CxNpExIwZARBhDjhboAEgof-YYF7s4I9di1HREv3QKyzadoXZ74PlelwJ7ejpLBl5lXRto">
  </div>
  <img id="BORDER" src="https://i.ibb.co/yd47GPy/laptop-screen.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thx ill try that